# How to concatenate a key in JSON response coming from API and display in VUE component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I need to concatenate a json key for displaying the contents based on the current language selected. In API I am getting the response and current language selected. The response is like below

```
{
  lang : "en"
  heading_ar: "قابل وتناول واستمتع بالاختبار الحقيقي"
  heading_en: "Meet, Eat & Enjoy the true test"
  description_ar: "<p>هناك حقيقة مثبتة منذ زمن طويل وهي أن المحتوى المقروء لصفحة</p>"
  description_en: "<p>It is a long established fact that a</p>"
  id: 1
}
```

in template I should display the contents. But I cannot able to concatenate `lang` in `heading` . I tried different ways but nothing is working.

```
<template>
<h1 class="banner-title">{{banner.home.heading_+banner.home.lang}}</h1>
</template>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template>
<h1 class="banner-title">{{banner.home.heading_en}}{{banner.home.lang}}</h1>
</template>
```

EDIT: after clarifying requirements

```
<template>
    <h1 class="banner-title">{{computedHeading}}</h1>
</template>
```

and to your script add [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```
computed: {
// a computed getter
  computedHeading: function () {
    if(this.banner.home.lang == "en"){
      return this.banner.home.heading_en
    }else{
      return this.banner.home.heading_ar
    } 
}
```

}

EDIT: after OP said he has many languages optimisation

Note that this does not need to be computed property, if your data is not changing only set this once

```
computed: {
// a computed getter
  computedHeading: function () {
        let prefix = "heading_"
        let headingPath = prefix+this.banner.home.lang
        return this.banner.home[headingPath]
  }
}
```

Comment: how this will work? I want to display either heading_en or heading_ar not both

Comment: That was not your question, I will make an edit to help you with that too

Comment: I need to concatenate json key. based on that I should take the value

Comment: computed property is working fine. but it has many languages so every language I should give condition.

Comment: Hope this new edit answers your question. Please in future tell all your requirements/scenarios in advance when asking the question

Comment: thank you so much  its working fine. Sorry for  not asking proper question

Answer (score 0):

```
With string interpolation {{`${banner.home.heading_} some text ${banner.home.lang}`}}
```

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: I tried like this to {{`${banner.home.heading_+banner.home.lang}`}} but not working

Comment: ${variable_or_function} text static ${other_variable_or_function} everything between those quotes